# Ubuntu Redistribution

Tags: virtualbox, license, open-source

I'd like to create a VirtualBox image of Ubuntu, install some open-source software to it, and make that publicly available.  The goal is to provide a ready-made image with some software already installed, to make it easy for beginners to learn some tools.

I'm reading through the IP licensing information on Ubuntu, trying to understand if this scenario is a "redistribution" or not.  I won't be making any changes to Ubuntu itself, only pre-installing some software.

**Does this constitute a redistribution, and if not, do I still have to remove all Ubuntu trademarks to make my image publicly available?**

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one: http://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/

Comment: I assume that you will distribute your image for free. I think this is OK, and I don't think that you should remove all Ubuntu trademarks. Instead you should state clearly in the documentation, that it is Ubuntu, and also link to the license web page. Probably you should also do something similar about VirtualBox (since you are distributing images for it). By the way, did you consider distributing a general compressed image file, that can be cloned into a USB pendrive or memory card, so that the computer can be booted from it? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS